# Flutter : PieChart Error: The argument type 'RxInt' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double?'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

acnt use int in piechart

code

```
PieChart(
              PieChartData(
                sections: [
                  PieChartSectionData(value: controller.vvip.value ,color: Color(0xff484AFF),showTitle: false),
                  PieChartSectionData(value: 476,color: Color(0xffD6A21E),showTitle: false),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

controller

```
RxInt vvip = 10.obs ;
```

error

```
Error: The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double?'.
```

Comment: double.parse(yourvariable) try like this.you supplaying integer you need to change double value

Comment: Can you write the code form?

Comment: which package used for piechart is syncfusion

Comment: package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart

Comment: int i = 1;
 print('hello ${i.toDouble()}');

User toDouble() method